# ESP32 Dimmable LED Panel with MOSFET

Tags: power, led, pwm, esp32, mosfet

I want to use ESP32 to control and use a dimmer for 6 LED panels in my bedroom. The specification of each panel is mentioned in the diagram. Although in the diagram it shows ONLY 1 MOSFET and 1 LED Panel but in reality there are 6 LED Panels therefore I am guessing that each of the 6 LED Panel will need a separate MOSFET.

[image]

I would like to know:

1. What MOSFET (Part number or model number, company name,  etc) should I use for the above LED panel connected with ESP32 (I guess voltage of ESP32 is 3.3 v) ?
2. Will each LED panel need separate MOSFET (6 LED Panels will need 6 seperate MOSFET) or can 1 MOSFET be connected to all 6 LED Panel ?
3. If I am using 6 LED Panels what should be the specification of Power Supply (Voltage & Amps) ?
4. If I use 6 set of MOSFET & LED Panels, can all MOSFETs be connected to a single PWM pin in ESP32 or does each MOSFET needs to be connected to separate PWM pins in ESP32 ?
5. Is the above circuit okay, or would you suggest some other components to be added apart from MOSFET?
6. What will be connection between power supply, LED and MOSFET. 
   I am guessing that 'Positive of Power Supply --> Positive of LED Panel', 'Negative of LED Panel -->  Source of MOSFET' and 'Drain of MOSFET --> Negative of Power Supply'. Kindly correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks.

---

To add more information regarding the LED panel:

1. It is 15W LED Panel (note it is not LED Bulb or LED Strip).
   Link to LED panel is [15W LED Panel](https://teknolite.in/project/plx-sq/)

[image]

2. Below is the picture of Driver that came with the LED Panel, note the below driver is non-dimmable.

[image]

Kindly help.

Comment: please provide a link to the datasheet for the LED panel .... if that is not available, then make and model of the LED panel .... or a web link to where it is sold

Comment: how do you want to dim a LED bulb with working voltage from 150 to 260 V? It will turn off under 150 and have full light over 150 V. it has a switching AC/DC power supply inside. use DC LED strips for the panel

Comment: Hi Juraj,
It is not LED bulb, it is a LED ceiling panel. I have added below more detail of the LED panel and picture of the original driver that came with the LED Panel. 
Note that the original Driver is non-dimmable.

Comment: bulb or panel, it is the same principle for 'AC LED' . the LED bulb has the driver build-in. for the panel you could replace the driver, but it is not easy to do it right and sure not a question for Arduino SE. perhaps it is easy, only connect the DC side with the MOSFET and use PWM, but I can't tell if the driver likes it

Answer (score 2):

Your plan has more flaws. First as Juraj wrote in a comment, you can't dim a switching power supply of the LED bulb. But this would not work as you plan even if you use a classic incandescent light bulb with AC. You can't control it with PWM. AC is dimmed with [phase control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-fired_controller), which requires a zero crossing detection to turn off power for part of the AC wave.

Comment: Hi, it is not LED bulb, it is a LED ceiling panel. I have added below more detail of the LED panel and picture of the original driver that came with the LED Panel. Note that the original Driver is non-dimmable.